# Update user fields programatically resets password

Tags: entities, users

When trying to update user (custom) fields programatically in drupal 7, I get the weird problem that whenever I do, my password is reset, my user is logged out, and I have to reset password to be able to log-in again.

I have tried a few different things, none seem to work, here's my code.

```
global $user;
global $language;
$fullUser = user_load($user->uid);

$updateUserParams = array();

$updateUserParams['language'] = $language->language;
$updateUserParams['field_first_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['firstName'];
$updateUserParams['field_surname'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['lastName'];

$year = $form_state['values']['birthdate']['year'];
$month = $form_state['values']['birthdate']['month'];
$day = $form_state['values']['birthdate']['day'];

$birthdate = date( "Y-m-d", strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day));

$updateUserParams['field_birthdate'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $birthdate;
$updateUserParams['gender'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['gender'];
$updateUserParams['field_address']['en'][0]['thoroughfare'] = $form_state['values']['street'];
$updateUserParams['field_address']['en'][0]['postal_code'] = $form_state['values']['postalCode'];
$updateUserParams['field_address']['en'][0]['locality'] = $form_state['values']['city'];
$updateUserParams['field_phone'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['phone'];

user_save($user, $updateUserParams);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nikit, your answer pushed me in the right direction, however, it wasn't correct.

the problem wasn't that I had the `pass` variable defined in my `$updateUserParams`, as you can see, I do not.

The problem was, that i had the `pass` variable defined in the `$user` I did my `user_save` with. I managed to fix the problem by unsetting the `pass` on my user object. And to be saved, I did the update on the `$fulluser` instead of the `$user` which is a global variable, and could potentially break things.

Here's the working code.

```
    global $user;
    global $language;
    $fullUser = user_load($user->uid);

    $updateUserParams = (array) $fullUser;

    $updateUserParams['language'] = $language->language;
    $updateUserParams['field_first_name'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['firstName'];
    $updateUserParams['field_surname'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['lastName'];

    $year = $form_state['values']['birthdate']['year'];
    $month = $form_state['values']['birthdate']['month'];
    $day = $form_state['values']['birthdate']['day'];

    $birthdate = date( "Y-m-d", strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day));

    $updateUserParams['field_birthdate'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $birthdate;
    $updateUserParams['gender'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['gender'];
    $updateUserParams['field_address']['en'][0]['thoroughfare'] = $form_state['values']['street'];
    $updateUserParams['field_address']['en'][0]['postal_code'] = $form_state['values']['postalCode'];
    $updateUserParams['field_address']['en'][0]['locality'] = $form_state['values']['city'];
    $updateUserParams['field_phone'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $form_state['values']['phone'];

    unset($fullUser->pass);
    unset($updateUserParams['pass']);

    user_save($fullUser, $updateUserParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look [user_save](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_save/7) there special code at the top, that prevent updating password if `pass` not provided on `$updateUserParams`. So please check your other modules or Rules, that possibly resetting password each time, then user_save called.